# Trajectory differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

The soluton of this differential equation describes the trajectory of a particle
considering the air resistance. Im wondering if anyone has a good way plot the solution in 2D.

[image]

```
       Clear[t]
solx = DSolve[{x''[t] + k x'[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, 
     x'[0] == v0 Cos[theta]}, x[t], t][[1, 1, 2]] // Simplify
soly = DSolve[{u''[t] + k u'[t] == -g, u'[0] == v0 Sin[theta], 
     u[0] == 0}, u[t], t][[1, 1, 2]] // Simplify
v0=10;(*m/s*)
k=1.;
theta=Pi/4;
```

**EDIT**

Just as a curiosity, an animation of the range in function of the angle:

```
Clear[t,theta]
g = 9.81;
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{solx, soly} /. t -> tt /. theta -> \[Theta], {tt, 0, 1.8}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 5}}], {\[Theta], Pi/10, Pi/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: `ParametricPlot[{solx, soly} /. g -> 9.8, {t, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
v0 = 10;
k = 1.;
theta = Pi/4;
g = 10;
solx = DSolve[{x''[t] + k x'[t] == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == v0 Cos[theta]}, x[t], t]
soly = DSolve[{u''[t] + k u'[t] == -g, u'[0] == v0 Sin[theta], u[0] == 0}, u[t], t]
ParametricPlot[{x[t], u[t]} /. solx /. soly, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To plot until it comes down to earth:

```
tf = t /. First@Solve[(u[t] /. soly) == 0 && t > .1, t]
ParametricPlot[{x[t], u[t]} /. solx /. soly, {t, 0, tf}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here you have the same, done with the vectorial form of `NDSolve[ ]`

```
th = Pi/4;
k = 1.;
v0 = 10;
s = {0, -g};
ds = NDSolveValue[
  {w'[t] == {0, 0}, w[0] == {0, -g},
   r''[t] + k r'[t] == w[t], r[0] == {0, 0}, r'[0] == v0 {Cos@th, Sin@th},
   WhenEvent[Last[r[t]] == 0, (tf = t; "StopIntegration")]},
  {r, w}, {t, 0, 10}]

ParametricPlot[Through[ds[t]][[1]], {t, 0, tf}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]